# Var Troubles! D:

Tags: javascript, variables

So..I'm making an incremental game, which each structure will give you a certain amount of Cookies. Cursors give you two Cookies, and I want Rep to give you five cookies. However, both of them give two Cookies, and I dunno how to change that. Here's my snippet.
Also, how do I make it so my total cps is displayed? CPS being cookies per second. I have that included, but it doesn't work either.

```
var cookies = 0;

function cookieClick(number){
  cookies = cookies + number;
  document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
};

var cps = 0;

function cps(cursors, rep){
  cps = cursors + rep;
  document.getElementById('cps').innerHTML = cps;
};

var cursors = 0;

function buyCursor(number){
  var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));     //works out the cost of this cursor
  if(cookies >= cursorCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
    cursors = cursors + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
    cookies = cookies - cursorCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
    document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
  };
  var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
}; 

var rep = 0;

function buyRep(){
  var repCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.2,rep));     //works out the cost of this rep
  if(cookies >= repCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the rep
    rep = rep + 1;                                   //increases number of rep
    cookies = cookies - repCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
    document.getElementById('rep').innerHTML = rep;  //updates the number of rep for the user
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
  };
  var nextCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.2,rep));       //works out the cost of the next rep
  document.getElementById('repCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  //updates the rep cost for the user
};


window.setInterval(function(){

  cookieClick(cursors);
  cookieClick(rep);

}, 1000);
```

Comment: A note, function declarations don't end with semicolon. Check your code here http://jshint.com for errors/warnings

Comment: I did, removed all unnecessary semicolons, but the cps function still will not work.

Comment: @elclanrs It's not a rule not to put semicolons after function declarations. Just a convention.

Comment: @AaditMShah: it's not a rule to put semicolons at all, or to put 5 semicolons in a row. Just best practice, if it's unnecesary semicolon there why put it?

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want us to show you how to multiply cursors by 2 and rep by 5 in `function cps()`?  Surely not.  I mean, you have multiplications in other functions.

Comment: I want it so that if I have 3 cursors, cps will display "Cookies Per Second: 6". I'd also like to change how much CPS each of my structures give out. At the moment, they both give out 2 CPS, and I'm not sure about how to change that.

Comment: You mention parts of this code don't work.  Have you looked in the developer tools console (control shift J on some browsers) to see if there are any console messages?  If there are, could you edit your question to include the console messages?

Comment: For the CPS function that I'm trying to do, I plug this into the console and it returns as undefined. ---- var cps = 0;

function cps(cursors, rep){
  cps = cursors + rep;
  document.getElementById('cps').innerHTML = cps;
}

Comment: I was thinking the code that you posted was part of a web site, and when you navigate to that web site with the browser, which then loads the code, there might be messages in the console.